# Data analysis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, sampling

I have a time vector in Matlab which does not have consistent sampling time, ex. `t = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2 2.9 3 3.1]`, I have another vector which is time based as `a = [2 5 2 4 5 7 8 0 10 1 0 25 6 14 5 2 7 98]`, when I plot(t,a) there is straight line connecting the two points with larger sampling time, how can I remove these gaps where the sampling time is not consistent and it jumps to larger value? I know defining NaN between `0.7` and `1.3` and also `2` and `2.9` in `t` and also in `a` for the same interval might help, but how to distinguish if sampling time changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following codes, and here are two approaches that you can make it:

- Approach 1: adding `nan`

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

t = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2 2.9 3 3.1]
a = [2 5 2 4 5 7 8 0 10 1 0 25 6 14 5 2 7 98]

dt = diff(t);
idx = find(dt > mode(dt));
tC = mat2cell(t',[idx(1),diff([idx,length(t)])]);
aC = mat2cell(a',[idx(1),diff([idx,length(t)])]);
nadd = dt(idx)/mode(dt);
T = [];
A = [];
for i = 1:length(nadd)
  T = [T; tC{i};ones(int32(nadd(i)),1)*nan];
  A = [A; aC{i};ones(int32(nadd(i)),1)*nan];
endfor
T = [T;tC{end}];
A = [A;aC{end}];

plot(T,A)
```

[image]

- Approach 2: dividing vector by intervals

```
clc;
clear;

t = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2 2.9 3 3.1]
a = [2 5 2 4 5 7 8 0 10 1 0 25 6 14 5 2 7 98]

dt = diff(t);
idx = find(dt > mode(dt));
tC = mat2cell(t',[idx(1),diff([idx,length(t)])]);
aC = mat2cell(a',[idx(1),diff([idx,length(t)])]);

hold on;
arrayfun(@(k) plot(tC{k},aC{k}),1:(length(idx)+1));
```

[image]

Comment: No, I do not need interpolation, in the example I need to add NaN between 0.7 an 1.3 and also between 2 and 2.9, and do the same in a vector for that interval

Comment: @FR I edited my answer, so you can see if it works for you as well